# Activity flashes/blink when changing frames

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager and it works just fine but when i add this to the listener 
OnPageSelected()
mViewBottomBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); it flashes, mViewBottomBar is a view form the actvitiy layout that it's outside the viewpager, these two are inside a relative layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It flashes because View.GONE sets the width and the height of your bottom bar to 0. The UI needs to update afterwards so thats why you see the flashing screen. To fix this problem use animations to hide your bottom bar and call View.GONE when animation ends, this will allow a smooth transition with no flashing.

Example:

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(
        TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
        TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
        TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
        TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 100);
animation.setDuration(200);
animation.setFillAfter(true);

animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
    {
        mViewBottomBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation)
    {

    }
});

mViewBottomBar.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: But it happens even when item isn't visible and i have the following condition if (mViewBottomBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            mViewBottomBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

Comment: What item? Be more clear, please. See the updated answer using animations. See if it works.